# How to bind dynamically generated array in ngModel, which is looping with ngFor?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have an object in my component, in that object there is an array, I want to bind it dynamically with `ngModel`. One way binding is happening but when i do some changes or add new array elements then model is not updating.

Html part

```
 <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-lg-6 pt-2 label-header" >Group </label>
             <button type="button" class="col btn btn-success m-2" (click)="addFieldGroup($event)">Add Group</button>
             <button type="button" class="col btn btn-danger m-2" (click)="deleteFieldGroup($event)">Delete Group</button>
            <div class="mt-2 col-lg-12 group-name ">
                <input *ngFor='let g of foo.general.group' type="text" class="form-control col-lg-12 general m-2" [(ngModel)]="g" value="{{ g }}" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
            </div>
  </div>
```

Component part

```
 foo = {
    "general": {
        "name": "sdfdf",      
        "group": ["sd","sdad","asdasdasd"]        
    }

 addFieldGroup(event){  
    this.foo.general.group.push('');
  }
  deleteFieldGroup(event){  
    this.foo.general.group.pop();
  }
```

ngModel is rendering "sd","sdad","asdasdasd" in seperate input fields but on doing some changes or adding new array elements, model is not changing. I am getting previous model only ie.

```
    "general": {
        "name": "sdfdf",      
        "group": ["sd","sdad","asdasdasd"]        
    }
```

But the name field is working perfectly with two way binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Adrita for giving me this idea but as the object is really large and having many arrays so it will be a hassle anyways what i did is

```
<div class="mt-2 col-lg-12 group-name ">
       <input *ngFor='let g of foo.general.group;let i=index;trackBy:trackByFn' type="text" class="form-control col-lg-12 general m-2" id="form-college-name" [(ngModel)]="foo.general.group[i]" [value]="foo.general.group[i]"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
</div>
```

And in component

```
foo = {
    "general": {
        "name": "sdfdf",      
        "group": []       
    }

 addFieldGroup(event){  
    this.foo.general.group.push('');
  }
  deleteFieldGroup(event){  
    this.foo.general.group.pop();
  }
  trackByFn(index: any, item: any) {
    return index;
  }
```

Comment: Without a reproducible link, it will be very difficult to see what is causing focus loose

Comment: Solved it, I needed a trackBy function, I am editing my answer with my new code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

Typescript:

```
modelGroups = []
```

Template:

```
<div class="mt-2 col-lg-12 group-name ">
  <input 
     *ngFor='let g of foo.general.group;let i = index' 
     [(ngModel)]="modelGroups[i]" 
     type="text" class="form-control col-lg-12 general m-2"  
     value="{{ g }}" 
     [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share stackbiltz

Comment: Please see my answer, I am not making a new array but it's working. The only issue is that input box is loosing focus as soon as type a character.

Answer (score 0):

The variable in your component.ts is foo. Try changing your input element's ngFor to

```
<input *ngFor='let g of foo.general.group' type="text" class="form-control col-lg-12 general m-2" [(ngModel)]="g" value="{{ g }}" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">
```